# Calling two Queue class function in a loop

Tags: c++, class, loops, queue

I have problem with this code of mine. Whenever i call two function of the class, and in those class, there is if-else statement, and print the output on screen, it will only run the if clause of the two functions and not the else. How can i fix this?

For example:
This is my Queue.h file:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

class Queue {
private:
    //private variables
    int arr_size;
    char *arr;
    int head;
    int tail;
    int count;
public:
    Queue(int); //constructor
             //functions
    int enqueue(char);
    int dequeue(char&);
};
#endif
```

This is my Queue.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Queue.h"
using namespace std;
Queue::Queue(int size) {
    //initializing
    arr_size = size;
    arr = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        arr[i] = NULL;
    }
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
    count = 0;
}
int Queue::enqueue(char value) {
    if (count<arr_size) //if array is not full, execute below
    {
        arr[tail++] = value;  //pass value of first-to-last element in array
        count++; //counting the input value
        cout << "\nEnqueue Value: "<< arr[tail-1];
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        tail = 0;
        cout << "\nArray is full. Value cannot be write: " << value;
        return -1;
    }
}
int Queue::dequeue(char &read_val) {
    if (count !=0) { //if array has elements, execute below
        read_val = arr[head]; //pass-by-reference the value of first-to-last element in array to parameter of function
        cout <<"\nDequeue Value: "<<read_val;
        arr[head] = NULL;
        count--;
        if (head++ == arr_size) {
            head = 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else if (count ==0) {
        cout << "\nArray is empty. Cannot be dequeue";
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And this is what my Source file:

```
#include "Queue.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Please enter the desired size of the array: ";
    cin >> n;
    char read_val = NULL;
    Queue myqueue(n);
    char arr[] = "Hello World, this is ELEC3150";
    int size = sizeof(arr)-1; 
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myqueue.enqueue(arr[count]);
        count++;
        myqueue.dequeue(read_val);
    }
```

If i enter the size of the array to be less than 5, it must print the error message saying the array is full in the enqueue function and the array is empty in the dequeue function but did not.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: Why does `main` have this variable `count`?  Why not just use `myqueue.enqueue(arr[i]);`

Comment: ... and finally, show us your queue.h.  We need an [mcve]

Comment: Why do you expect your queue to become full if you dequeue immediately after you enqueue? Why do you expect error in dequeue function if you dequeue always from one-element queue?

Comment: I understand now. Because i was trying to enqueue 5 character then dequeue 5 character. Repeat until ithe end of the array arr in my main. So if i separate the dequeue and the enqueue to 2 separate for loop, in a while loop, it still exist.